# SELECT LIST retorna só um valor e não uma lista

Tags: sql, sql-select, sybase

Olá,

Eu tenho duas tabelas, uma que representa os grupos (certification.certification_adm_email - colunas começam com "caem"), e a outra de usuários (admin.dbuser - colunas começam com "user"). Entre elas existe uma tabela nxn fazendo a intermediação (certification.caem_dbuser - colunas começam com "cadb"). Eu preciso fazer uma consulta que me retorne para um grupo, todos os usuários cadastrados nele. Porém, minha busca está retornando apenas um resultado para esse campo que chamei de members_desc. Alguém poderia ajudar, por favor?

Por enquanto, meu código está assim:

```
                 SELECT
                    caem_seq,
                    caem_code,
                    caem_desc,
                    cadb_user_seq,
                    cadb_caem_seq,
                    (SELECT LIST(user_name || '-' || user_elogin || '-' || cmpn_desc || '-' || user_email, '<br>' ORDER BY user_name)
                       FROM admin.dbuser
                       JOIN admin.company ON cmpn_seq = user_cmpn_seq
                      WHERE user_seq = cadb_user_seq
                    ) AS members_desc
          FROM  certification.certification_adm_email
          LEFT JOIN certification.caem_dbuser ON cadb_caem_seq = caem_seq
```

Comment: Para a gente te ajudar melhor, crie um exemplo do site http://sqlfiddle.com/ com dados e exemplo do resultado que você espera do `SQL`

Comment: É importante você marcar a tag do SGBD utilizado para facilitar quem vai responder.

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver, obrigada!

Funcionou com o seguinte código:

```
            SELECT
                        caem_seq,
                        caem_code,
                        caem_desc,
                        (SELECT LIST('-' || user_name || '-' || user_elogin || '-' || cmpn_desc || '-' || user_email, '<br>' ORDER BY user_name)
                           FROM certification.caem_dbuser
                           JOIN admin.dbuser ON cadb_user_seq = user_seq
                           JOIN admin.company ON cmpn_seq = user_cmpn_seq  
                          WHERE caem_seq = cadb_caem_seq
                        ) AS members_desc
              FROM  certification.certification_adm_email
```

Answer (score -2):

Ao usar o `members_desc` como um `select` você obriga a instrução a trazer somente um resultado
Você pode criar uma temp com esse select e fazer `left join` no `from`

```
SELECT
     caem_seq,caem_code,caem_desc,cadb_user_seq,cadb_caem_seq,

FROM  
     certification.certification_adm_email
     LEFT JOIN certification.caem_dbuser ON cadb_caem_seq = caem_seq
     left join (select user_name + '-' + user_elogin + '-' + cmpn_desc + '-' + user_email 'members_desc ',  '<br>'
                       FROM admin.dbuser
                       JOIN admin.company ON cmpn_seq = user_cmpn_seq
                      
                    ) AS x on user_seq = cadb_user_seq
```

Algo assim ...

Comment: Oi gente, obrigada! Com esse código, aparece o seguinte erro "[Sybase][JDBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Derived table 'x' has no name for column 2".